# Spring Integration - Reliable TCP for high volume application

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, nio, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration for TCP server which keeps connections to a few thousand clients. I need the server to throttle clients in case of excessive load and not to lose messages.

My server configuration:

```
<task:executor id="myTaskExecutor"
    pool-size="4-8"
    queue-capacity="0"
    rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverTcpConFact"
    type="server"
    port="60000"
    using-nio="true"
    single-use="false"
    so-timeout="300000"
    task-executor="myTaskExecutor" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInboundAdapter"
    channel="tcpInbound"
    connection-factory="serverTcpConFact" />

<channel id="tcpInbound" />

<service-activator input-channel="tcpInbound"
    ref="myService"
    method="test" />

<beans:bean id="myService" class="org.test.tcpserver.MyService" />
```

Since the default task executor for the connection factory is unbounded, I use a pooled task executor to prevent out of memory errors.

A simple client for load testing:

```
public class TCPClientTest {
    static Socket socket;
    static List<Socket> sl = new ArrayList<>();
    static DataOutputStream out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 60000);
            sl.add(socket);
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeBytes("connection " + i + "\r\n");
            System.out.println("Using connection #" + i);
        }
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

When I run it, the server only receives about 10-20 messages and then the client gets the "Connection refused: connect" exception. After that the server can't accept any new connections anymore, even after the connection timeout. Increasing the pool size only helps to get a little bit more messages.

**EDIT**

I'm using Spring Integration 3.0.2.RELEASE. For production I'm using 8-40 threads, but it only makes this test to fail later, after several hundred connections.

MyService.test() doesn't do much...

```
public class MyService {
    public void test(byte[] input) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + new String(input));
    }
}
```

[Here is the log with trace level logging.](http://www.filedropper.com/server-log)

[Sources](http://www.filedropper.com/spring-integration-tcp-test)

Comment: What version of Spring Integration? What does `MyService.test()` do? Given that you are only sending a short message on each socket, serially, I would not expect any threading issues for this test case (although 4-8 threads would likely be totally inadequate for a real application with that number of sockets). I suggest you turn on trace level logging on the server side.

Comment: @Gary Russell Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what the problem is, please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

The issue is the `CALLER_RUNS` rejection policy with a `0` length queue in the executor.

There is one thread that handles all IO events (usually `myTaskExecutor-1`); when a read event fires he queues an execution to read the data; the reader thread queues an execution to assemble the data (which will block until a complete message - in your case terminated by the CRLF - arrives).

In this case, when there are no threads available, the `CALLER_RUNS` policy means the IO selector thread does the read, and becomes the assembler thread, which blocks waiting for data that won't arrive because he is blocked and would later have read the data after scheduling a different thread to block. Because he is blocked, he can't handle new accept events.

Here is a log from my test showing the issue...

```
TRACE: [May-18 10:43:38,923][myTaskExecutor-1] tcp.connection.TcpNioServerConnectionFactory - Port 60000 SelectionCount: 2
DEBUG: [May-18 10:43:38,923][myTaskExecutor-1] tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - localhost:58509:60000:bdc36c59-c31b-470e-96c3-6270e7c46a2f Reading...
DEBUG: [May-18 10:43:38,924][myTaskExecutor-1] tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - localhost:58509:60000:bdc36c59-c31b-470e-96c3-6270e7c46a2f Running an assembler
TRACE: [May-18 10:43:38,924][myTaskExecutor-1] tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - localhost:58509:60000:bdc36c59-c31b-470e-96c3-6270e7c46a2f Nio message assembler running...
DEBUG: [May-18 10:43:38,926][myTaskExecutor-1] tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer - Available to read:0
```

The second line shows the selector thread being used to do the read; he detects that an assembler is needed for this socket, and becomes the assembler, blocking, waiting for data.

Do you really believe there will be an issue using an unbounded task executor? These events are generally pretty short lived so threads will be recycled pretty quickly.

Increasing the executor's queue capacity above 0 should help too, but it won't completely assure the problem won't happen (although a large queue size is unlikely to be hit).

I am yet not sure how to fix this, aside from using a dedicated task executor for the IO selector and reader threads so they will never be used as an assembler.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and for the explanation. I think that in the real world scenario it's very unlikely to get a problem with an unbounded task executor, but at least the same test crashes after ~4000 connections with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` if I use it. I think it would be good to have something that works regardless of the load. I'll open a JIRA issue.

Comment: I have wanted to write something like this [CallerBlocksPolicy](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/63038cdd886e00ef01b8) for some time (to cover other use cases), but never got around to it. 8 threads are still not enough for your test case, because it times out trying to launch an assembler. However, with 80 threads as shown in the gist, I just killed your test after it created nearly 9000 connections and was still going strong.

Comment: I've tried your `CallerBlocksPolicy`, but as you said, it still doesn't work well with 8 threads. When you said that it times out trying to launch an assembler, which timeout did you mean? I don't mind increasing the number of threads, but I don't get why 8 threads still causes the test to fail, even when we don't use the `CALLER_RUNS` rejection policy anymore? Sure the number of threads in the pool should affect performance, but why does it also affect stability?

Comment: My mistake - of course the queue capacity has to be at least 1 so the `offer` has a chance of succeeding; I didn't mean to imply it still hangs just that some requests time out. With a max of 8 and a capacity  of 1, I do see occasional timeouts but it keeps running. I am close to 1000 in a few minutes. I have opened the JIRA issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3410 watch it if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid something is still wrong. I've tried to set the queue capacity to 1 and got some strange behavior. The client sent 115 messages before timing out, but the server only received the first 106 of them. Then after 10 seconds (CallerBlocksPolicy's maxWait) I got 4 `RejectedExecutionException`, after another 10 seconds - more `RejectedExecutionException` and so on before I finally got 3 `org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Timed out writing to ChannelInputStream, probably due to insufficient threads in a fixed thread pool`.

Comment: Right - this isn't the final solution, but it improves things in that the selector thread is no longer deadlocked - if the selector thread is unlucky, it will block here instead and timeout (causing an exception); you might lose a socket or two, but it will recover. With `CALLER_RUNS` it can never recover. I have the complete fix working; I am writing the documentation and will create a pull request shortly. I just offered this as a stop gap.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I'll be watching the JIRA.

Comment: I've tested 4.0.1 and it works great, even with the queue capacity set to 0 for both executors. Thank you for the fix! Do you know the timeframe when 3.0.3 might be released?

Comment: We don't currently have it scheduled, but we can cut the release at any time - when do you need it? You can `test` with 3.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (see the [project page for maven repo details](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) - click on the '3.0.3 Snapshot in the quick start drop down - testing is ok, but I wouldn't recommend putting a snapshot into production.

Comment: This or the next week would be perfect.

Comment: 3.0.3 is now available with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

yesterday I did write a sample just to create tcp high performance server code using spring integration.  I tested it successfully with 1000 concurrent client requests using JMeter TCP sampler.

Here is the code - https://github.com/rajeshgheware/spring-integration-samples including JMeter test config file.

I successfully tested with 1000 concurrent tcp client requests on 64bit Laptop having Intel core i5 M520 2.4GHz (both the server code and JMeter test running on this machine)

I also tried with 1500 concurrent client requests but observed that server could not honor many requests.  I will keep trying to enhance this code to serve 10000 concurrent client requests (I know I may need to get good EC2 machine from Amazon for this test :) )