# TCP server and high volume

Tags: spring-integration

I am using an SI server in my current project and have been pretty happy with it. I basically took the server straight from the examples. Communication should be request/response. I really haven´t noticed any problem but given a potentially high connection volume should I be handling incoming connects differently? Would it be "best" to have channels with pollers to throttle a bit better or is all this something that I should just fiddle with?

```
<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server"
        type="server"
        port="${port}"
        using-nio="true"
        so-tcp-no-delay="true"/>

<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway connection-factory="server"
        request-channel="toSA"
        error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:channel id="toSA" 
        datatype="java.lang.String"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="toSA" 
        ref="Controller" 
        method="handle"/>

<int:transformer id="errorHandler"
        input-channel="errorChannel"
        expression="payload.failedMessage.payload + ':' + payload.cause.message"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indirectly control connections and throughput by limiting the number of threads available for handling the connections and I/O. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716830/spring-integration-reliable-tcp-for-high-volume-application/23723556#23723556) - be sure to read all the comments.

Also see the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#note_nio) for more information.

I would not suggest trying to use channels/pollers for this purpose.